# error 405 while validating with php

Tags: php, validation, visual-studio-2012, error-handling

hello guys i am new here... i am using visual studio and i am trying to run a simple php validation, but seems like the debugging mode is not reading my php file for some sake reason.

i have this html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>learning ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>learning ajax</h1>

    <h2>Ajax Post requests</h2>

    <form method="POST" action="files/ajax.php">


        <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></p>

        <input  type="submit" value="validate"/>
    </form>
    <a href="files/ajax.json">load ajax JSON</a>
    <script src="js/parser.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Tutsplus.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ajax5.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

please do ignore the linked scripts, i have no problems with it... so on the action in the form as u can see i have a trigger for a file called ajax.php on which is writen this:

```
   <?php
// Variable to check
 $email = $_POST['email'];
// Validate email
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    echo("$email is a valid email address");
} else {
    echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}
?>
```

e problem is it does not echo anything, in fact it showes me error 405 not allowed http request which is very strange... the same thing happens with json files but i can understand google chrome has some restriction and i can open it with flag, i can see there are 2 - 3 topicks similar to mine but i cound not find the answer i am looking for there

ty and i hope you guys can help me

Comment: how are you using this, as `file:///` directly in the browser? have you a webserver with php installed and running properly?

Comment: here http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html read that and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405 and keep Googling this error. There are too many possible duplicates.

Comment: i just have been told i need some security token to make post requests on local host..

Comment: i am using my php file as localhost://files/ajax.php